# Unzipping a file and ignoring 'junk files' added by OS X

Tags: ruby, zip

I am using code like the following to unzip files in Ruby:

```
def unzip_file (file)
  Zip::ZipFile.open(file) do |zip_file|
    zip_file.each do  |f| 
      puts f.name if f.file?
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to ignore all files generated by compress zip in Mac such as: .DS_Store, etc. How can I best do it?

Comment: Wait, is your question how not to include them in the zip, or how to ignore them when printing?

Answer (score 6):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(file) do |zip_file|
  names = zip_file.select(&:file?).map(&:name)
  names.reject!{|n| n=~ /\.DS_Store|__MACOSX|(^|\/)\._/ }
  puts names
end
```

That regular expression says,

- Throw away files

  - that have `.DS_Store` in the name,
  - that have `__MACOSX` in the name,
  - or that have `._` at the beginning of the name (`^`) or right after a `/`.

That should cover all the 'junk' files and hopefully not hit any others.

If you want more than just the names—if you want to process the non-junk files—then instead you might do the following:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(file) do |zip_file|
  files = zip_file.select(&:file?)
  files.reject!{|f| f.name =~ /\.DS_Store|__MACOSX|(^|\/)\._/ }
  puts files.map(&:names) # or do whatever else you want with the array of files
end
```